# How to (literally) create a makefile (for c in linux)?

Tags: c++, linux, console, makefile, createfile

I've been searching for a while but I've not seen any sources that explains the CONSOLE to MAKEFILE part. Or it could be so obvious I'm missing it.

I have the contents (rules and syntax) that would go into a make file and the source codes, but I don't know how to "create/write" the makefile as a file. (I'm assuming it's a file. Otherwise, shout!)

So, suppose I am on the console on a linux machine. What would I type into the black box of wonders in order to create a makefile so that I could insert the rules?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: You use a text editor. `vi makefile`, `emacs makefile`, etc.

Comment: type `vi Makefile`   .. also maybe you should google this first

Comment: Any editor you have installed.  Make sure it isn't set up to turn tabs into spaces.  Other than that it is just a text file.

Comment: I recommend `emacs` (or `gedit`) over `vi` but it is really a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I am on the console on a linux machine. What would I type into the black box of wonders in order to create a makefile so that I could insert the rules?

You would type the name of your favorite text editor (or an editor installed on your machine, such as `VI`). Type `vi Makefile`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and wait for the `VI` to open. In the `VI` press <kbd>I</kbd> to enter the input mode, type up the content of your makefile, press <kbd>ESC</kbd>, type `:wq`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again. You are done!

Now that you are back on the command line, type `cat Makefile` to double-check that you entered everything correctly.

One thing to keep in mind when typing up your makefile is the tabs: they are optional in your C programs, but in makefiles they are mandatory. You cannot replace them with several spaces - it must be a `TAB` character in the file in order for `make` to interpret your file properly.